# PHP script causes FastCGI process to crash

Tags: php, apache, mod-fcgid

I have a php script that loads a webpage from a url passed from the client, parses it and sends results to the client.

When running on my development environment (laptop with windows 7 & wamp installed), it works perfectly, but when uploaded to the server (windows server 2008 R2 + php 5.3.6 + apache 2.2 + mod_fcgid 2.3.9), running it results with an "Internal Server Error".

I can see how the FastCGI process, handling the request, memory consumption rises up to a point where it gets suspended and terminates unexpectedly.

The apache error log shows these 2 messages:

```
(OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : mod_fcgid: get overlap result error, referer: http://some_domain.com/NL-Analysis/getDomainResults

(OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function, referer: http://some_domain.com/NL-Analysis/getDomainResults
```

I've tried finding solutions on the internet based on the error log, most of what I found pointed me to the mod_fcgid configurations.
I've tried to change some of the mod_fcgid directives and limits, but it didn't help.

Currently the mod_fcgid is configures with these parameters in httpd.conf:

```
FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000
FcgidIOTimeout 7200
FcgidConnectTimeout 7200
FcgidBusyScanInterval 7200
FcgidBusyTimeout 7200
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000
FcgidMaxProcesses 80
FcgidIdleTimeout 7200
FcgidMaxRequestInMem 100000000000
FcgidProcessLifeTime 7200
```

I will be happy to provide any other inputs.

Can anybody think of a way to prevent the FastCGI process from terminating?

Thanks,
Alon.